# Combine 2 json_decode requests into 1 PHP variable

Tags: php, json, shopify

There is an Shopify API limit of 250 products so in order to get all product data I need to combine all pages into one PHP variable. So far I have the following but it doesn't work. Should I be defining $test as an array?

PHP is not my strong point so I've probobaly got the syntax all wrong. I just need to be able to read the data provided by both URL's defined as `$productspageone` and `$productspagetwo`

```
$test = array();
$productspageone = json_decode(httpGet($apiUrl . "/admin/products.json?limit=250&page=1"));
$productspagetwo = json_decode(httpGet($apiUrl . "/admin/products.json?limit=250&page=2"));

$test = json_decode(productspageone);
$test = json_decode($test=json_decode(productspagetwo);
```

Comment: How about passing true as the second parameter for json_decode (to return an array) then merging the 2 arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
it will decode responsed to arrays, then u have to merge them, u will have everything in the variable now

```
$productspageone = json_decode(httpGet($apiUrl . "/admin/products.json?limit=250&page=1"),true);
$productspagetwo = json_decode(httpGet($apiUrl . "/admin/products.json?limit=250&page=2"),true);

$test = array_merge($productspageone,$productspagetwo);
```

Comment: ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2] & ['a'=>3, 'b'=>4] What result do you expect? And if they are objects ?

Comment: I'm getting a JSON error, which I know will be hard to investigate for you: 'Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)'

Answer (score 1):

Yuo can make an array of all that items

```
$test = [ $productspageone, $productspagetwo ];
```

Comment: I'm getting a JSON error 'Unexpected token A in json...'